# table - with multiline entries in a single row

Tags: tables

I need to create a table like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXmVv.png]

I tried to do that with LaTeX with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\bfseries\arraybackslash }X}
\usepackage[pdftex,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{7ex}}|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
Monday \\ 21st March & Tuesday \\ 22nd March & Wednesday \\ 23rd March & Thursday 24th March & Friday \\ 25th March & Saturday \\ 26th March & Sunday \\ 27th March \\
\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

that resulted in the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRfTS.png]

I tried searching around but couldn't find much help.
What should I change in my code to get the desired result?

Please feel free to edit my question/tags for clarity/accuracy

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\` in a tabularx environment is for a new row, not a break in a cell.

For a break in a cell, you can use `\linebreak`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries}X}
\usepackage[pdftex,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
Monday \linebreak 21st March & 
Tuesday \linebreak 22nd March & 
Wednesday \linebreak 23rd March & 
Thursday \linebreak 24th March & 
Friday \linebreak 25th March & 
Saturday \linebreak 26th March & 
Sunday \linebreak 27th March \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx heading]

Comment: Exactly solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In `tabularx` (and other "classic") tables, don't use `\\` inside cells. In your case, you can use `makecell` package and the `thead` command, which enables the use of `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\bfseries\arraybackslash }X}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
    \hline
\thead{Monday\\ 21st March} 
    & \thead{Tuesday\\ 22nd March} 
        & \thead{Wednesday\\ 23rd March} 
            & \thead{Thursday\\ 24th March} 
                & \thead{Friday\\ 25th March} 
                    & \thead{Saturday\\ 26th March} 
                        & \thead{Sunday\\ 27th March} \\
    \hline
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7                            \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
The use of the `tabularray` package simplifies the code and gives better results. Its syntax enables manual break of a cell's content with `{text1 \\ text2}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{7}{X[c]}},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
             }
{Monday\\ 21st March} 
    & {Tuesday\\ 22nd March} 
        & {Wednesday\\ 23rd March} 
            & {Thursday\\ 24th March} 
                & {Friday\\ 25th March} 
                    & {Saturday\\ 26th March} 
                        & {Sunday\\ 27th March} \\
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7                 \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. There's a solution for everything in LaTeX. This TeX.SE forum is wonderful. Never expected such a fast response

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the contents into two table rows, one for the days, a second for the dates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries}X}
\usepackage[pdftex,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
Monday     & Tuesday    & Wednesday  & Thursday   & Friday     & Saturday   & Sunday     \\
21st March & 22nd March & 23rd March & 24th March & 25th March & 26th March & 27th March \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```